# Solve $ sin(z) = 3i$ for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ with domain constraints on $z$.The answer should be in the form z =.....

Tags: calculus, complex-numbers

I need help for an assignment
Solve for $z \in \mathbb{C}$ equation $\sin(z) = 3 i$,
knowing that the real part of $e^{iz}$ is negative, and the real part of $z$ lies in the interval $[0,2π]$.
The answer should be in the form z =.....

Comment: but we also have $\sin (\pi -i \text{arcsinh}(3))=3 i$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way is to use
$$
\sin z=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}
$$
so, setting $w=e^{iz}$ we get
$$
w^2-1=-6w
$$
so
$$
w=3\pm\sqrt{10}
$$
If you set $z=x+iy$, the solutions become
$$
e^{-y}e^{ix}=3+\sqrt{10}=(\sqrt{10}+3)e^{2k\pi i}
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
e^{-y}e^{ix}=-(\sqrt{10}-3)=(\sqrt{10}-3)e^{\pi i+2k\pi i}
$$
Can you finish?

Comment: I got to that point, but now I must write it in the form z=.....

Comment: @Bonang In the first case, $y=-\log(\sqrt{10}+3)=\log(\sqrt{10}-3)$ and $ix=2k\pi i$, so $z=2k\pi+i\log(\sqrt{10}-3)$. The other case is similar.